# LIBGDX - 90,000 Cones

Tags: java, libgdx, opengl-3

I am making a program that generates images like this by placing pixels on a 300 x 300 Pixmap
[image: Pixelated]
Which is nice, but the pixelation detracts a bit from the organic effect I'm looking for. So I made it render Voronoi cells instead of pixels like so:
[image: Voronoi]

```
public void render(Color[][] pixels, HashSet<Point> edge) {
        Gdx.gl.glEnable(GL20.GL_DEPTH_TEST);

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
                Color coneColor;
                if (pixels[i][j] != null) {
                    coneColor = new Color(pixels[i][j]);
                  coneColor.lerp(background, 1 - coneColor.a);
                  coneColor.a = 1;
                    shapeRenderer.setColor(coneColor);
                    shapeRenderer.cone(vertices[i][j].x, vertices[i][j].y, -100, 1.5f, 1.5f, 8);
                }
            }
        shapeRenderer.setColor(background);
        for (Point e : edge) {
            shapeRenderer.cone(vertices[e.getX()][e.getY()].x, vertices[e.getX()][e.getY()].y, -100, 1.5f, 1.5f, 8);
        }
        shapeRenderer.end();
    }
```

Which is fine for a small number of cones, but, as you can imagine, it does poorly for the upper limit of 90,000 cones. I've tried instances arrays, but libgdx does not seem to support glVertexAttribDivisor. I need to retain the ability to pan and zoom. What alternatives should I look into, or how can I make instancing work?

Comment: Not sure what you try to achieve exactly. But you might be able to make an image out of your final generation and just display that and dump the voronoi diagram.

Comment: @MennoGouw That is my fall-back strategy if I cannot find a way to get the GPU to do it for me.

Comment: 90.000 voronoi polygons makes at least 180k triangles. I have not much experience with 3D but that is a lot if you ask me. Yes current gen titles might have a tenfold of that but most stuff is being instanced, each triangle you create is unique. The thing is LibGDX is not current gen and it's no C++ either. Not saying you should give up but I do think your stretching the limits, but that can be a good thing and it's very interesting what you are trying to accomplish.